# retrieving values from an array of map (the map is inside an object)

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and there is an array of map inside the object. I have to access the values of map present in each object.

Here is the object:

```
public class DiscoveredProduct 
{
    private String approvedOn;
    private String rolledBackOn;
    private Map<String, Object> raw_attributes[];
    private Map<String, Object> product_attributes[];
    private Map<String, Object> norm_attributes[];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Those member variables are not maps, but arrays of maps.

Comment: Your question is not that much clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// we iterate over all arrays of Map
for (Map<String,Object> map : raw_attributes){
    // we iterate over all values of the current map
    for (Entry<String,Object> entry  : map.entrySet()){            
      String key = entry.getKey();
      Object value = entry.getValue();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that code, you can't access the values within these Map (arrays, btw!).

What you can do:

1. Change the fields from *private* to *public*; or at least package protected (not recommended)
2. Think up an **interface** that your class DiscoveredProduct can provide.

For example:

```
 public Object getRawAttributeFor(int index, String key)
```

which would simply

```
   return raw_attributes[index].get(key)
```

(of course, you would need proper checking on those input parameters)

A more convenient interface could look like

```
public List<Object> getRawAttributesFor(String key)
```

This time, you would simply iterate your array of Maps, and return all those values where a map knows that key.

Finally: read about java naming conventions. You only use the _ char within SOME_CONSTANT; but nowhere else.